# Use readline to read txt file python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline

I been working on this for hours and I cant get it right, any help would be appreciated! My question is how do I use the function `.readline()` to read until the end of a text file? I know that `.readlines()` work as well but I'm trying to process one line at a time.

Here's what I have for my code so far:

```
    a = open("SampleTxt.txt","r")

    While True:

        a.readline()
```

My problem is that I get an infinite loop when I run this, shouldn't it have stopped once it couldn't read a line any more?

Answer (score 35):

`a.readline()` will return `''` an empty string when no more data is available, you need to check that and then break your `while`, eg:

```
while True:
    line = a.readline()
    if not line: 
        break
```

If it's not purely for learning purposes then you really should be using a `with` statement and for-loop to process the file, line by line:

```
with open('SampleTxt.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        pass # do something
```

It's more clear as to your intent, and by using the `with` block, the fileobj will be released on an exception or when the block ends.

Comment: The second method still reads the file line by line and does not load the whole file into memory, right?

Comment: @nishant yes that better/efficient memory usage